# Exeception while executing script: [{}]java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'httpResponse' on null object

Tags: groovy

Trying to read raw response using groovy script with below snippet:

```
    def DownloadLink="https://bestbuyuat.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/4519d6eb1b592c90a531c8866e4bcb4d/file"
    def snowuserauth="Basic"
    def userCredentials2="${username}:${passwd}"
​    def httpConn =  new URL(DownloadLink).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    basicAuth1 = "${snowuserauth} " + new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userCredentials2.getBytes()));
    println("*** encoded1 "+basicAuth1);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth1);
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    int responseCode1 = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    *def rawResponse = context.httpResponse.getRawResponseBody();
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawResponse);
```

While compiling the code, I am getting error mentioned below:

{returnCode=1, errorStream={returnCode=-1000, errorStream=Exeception while executing script: [{}]java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'httpResponse' on null object}}

I would like to understand what exactly "context" is here.

Comment: the variable `context` s not declared in your code

Comment: Using internal APIs a sure way to run into problems with new JDKs.  There is `java.util.Base64` since java8.

Comment: @daggett what should be the correct way to declare it ? and what should variable "context" contain?

Comment: The answer depends on where and how you are executing your script. For simple script execution replace last 2 lines in your code with `def inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream()`